Is there a way for hitting the host.docker.internal from local machine?
Quickly about service
While writing docker compose for service i ran into issue. There are 4 parts that are required for service to fully work e2e on docker that is frontend in angular, backend in c# .net 6, azure function that is triggered by file on azure blob (not important in that issue) and azurite. Frontend task is to put files into azure storage after receiving SAS token embedded into URI address that backend creates. This fully work.
What's the issue
When containerized SAS URI created by backend application looks like: http://host.docker.internal:10000/devstoreaccount1/user-uploads/3415dfde-636c-4f4e-b7ef-bfeb456466f3.zip.zip?{SAS_TOKEN_PART} and with that frontend application opened locally on machine cannot do request as DNS can't resolve its name. And i want to be able to connect to azurite from outside the docker from frontend application (it's possible only the address is issue). I would like to omit conditional compilation on backend with replacing strings when it's in docker environment. I believe there is a solution i just can't find it.
Docker compose:
Parts of docker-compose.yml were censored but i think context is meaningless in that case.
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: CENSORED
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - azurite
    environment:
      - DOCKER_URL=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://host.docker.internal:10000/devstoreaccount1;
    volumes:
      - "${HOME}/.azure:/root/.azure"
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
  azurite:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    ports:
      - 10000:10000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    command: azurite --loose --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --blobPort 10000
  functions:
    build:
      context: CENSORED
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7071:7071
    depends_on:
      - azurite
  frontend:
    build:
      context: CENSORED
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:4200

My specs

Macbook Pro M2 Pro

It should also be working with windows.

Tried with creating networks and putting everything in network

Tried adding


extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

The url hasn't change at all and connection didn't went through.

In this answer I describe a reverse-proxy setup that avoids needing to know any of these host names at all.  Will a setup like that work for you here?

Reverse proxy won't work here (without changing frontend code) so I will just add some environment specific code for backend (If DOCKER_URL not null Replace address from docker.hosts.internal to localhost)

But still thanks for the suggestion. In new project I would likely go with that solution.
